# Insert multiple table data into temp table as a time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having 3 tables like below.

**Table A:**(Having one column Employee id)

```
Employee Id
   101
   102
   103
```

**Table B:**(Having One column EmployeeName)

```
EmpName
Sai
sarath
vijay
```

**Table C**:(Having One column DeptName)

```
DeptName**.
IT
ACCOUNTS
MANAGEMENT
```

Here i want to insert all three table columns values into one temp table.
Like

```
Create table #mytable (employeeid nvarchar(255),empname nvarchar(255),deptname nvarchar(255))

insert into #mytable (employeeid)

select employeeid from tableA
insert into #mytable (empname)

select empname from tableB
insert into #mytable (deptname)

select deptname from tableC
```

But here my temp table (i.e.) #mytable gives me result like  below table.

```
**Employeeid                Empname              DeptName**
    101                          null                  null
    102                          null                  null
    103                          null                  null
    null                        sai                    null
    null                       Sarath                  null
    null                        vijay                  null
    null                        null                   IT
    null                        null                    ACCOUNTS
    null                        null                    MANAGEMENT
```

But i wants to display only data rows not null values.Please give me any suggestions for insert all three table i.e A,B,C at a time into temp table i.e #mytable.And display only data containing rows.

And i have tried query like below

> 

```
 insert into tb_MBUPSheetData123 ([BusinessStrategyMessaging],Capability,[DealSource],Language,LicenseType,[Proactive activity],[Proposal Type],RFXSolution,
   SLBusinessSolutionArea,SolutionForProposal,SupportingSolution,Conversations,TopicForProposal,SalesDeskAgentAlias)

values ((select [BusinessStrategyMessaging] from tb_MBUPSheetData where BusinessStrategyMessaging is not null),
(select [DealSource]  FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where DealSource is not null),
(select [Capability] FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where Capability is not null),
 (select [Language] FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where Language is not null)
 ,(select [LicenseType] FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where LicenseType is not null),

(select [Proactive activity]  FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where [Proactive activity] is not null),
(select [ProposalType] FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where [Proposal Type] is not null),
(select[RFXSolution] FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where RFXSolution is not null),
(select [SLBusinessSolutionArea] FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where SLBusinessSolutionArea is not null),
(select [SolutionForProposal]FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where SolutionForProposal is not null),
(select [SupportingSolution] FROM tb_MBUPSheetData  where SupportingSolution is not null),
 (select Conversations FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where Conversations is not null),
 (select [TopicForProposal] FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where TopicForProposal is not null),
 (select [SalesDeskAgentAlias]  FROM tb_MBUPSheetData where SalesDeskAgentAlias is not null))
```

But i am getting below error

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

First your three table must have a foreign key relation like employee id noe you can write syntax like

```
insert into mytable(employeeid,empname,deptname) select a.Eamployee_Id,b.EmpName,c.DeptName from table_a a,table_b b,table_c c where a.Eamployee_Id=b.Eamployee_Id and a.Eamployee_Id=c.Eamployee_Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if you want all entries at a time in #temp table:-

```
insert into #mytable values(select employeeid from tableA where_condition,select empname from tableB where_condition,select deptname from tableC where_condition);
```

Comment: I am getting error like  "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @user3643469 have you given the correct "where condition" as i wrote in the ans?

Comment: you can give condition as : insert into temp values((select id from empid where id=101),(select EmpName from empname where EmpName='Sai'),(select DeptName from empdept where DeptName='IT'));